# Giving layers different optimize settings in Fireworks

Tags: export, adobe-fireworks

Each slice can have different optimize settings, however overlapping objects can't be exported to separate files using slices.

Exporting layers solves this problem nicely, however it uses the Document's optimize settings. I'd like one object to be exported as a GIF, another as PNG32 for example.

Is there some way of attaching optimize settings to layers?